# Handle document processing that exceed memory limits with Elasticsearch

Tags: ruby, json, garbage-collection, elasticsearch, tire

I am using **Tire** as the Ruby wrapper for **Elasticsearch**. My problem is that I need to load 100,000 documents into memory and do kind of complex computations on them. The current procedure looks like this:

> 1. Load all documents
> 2. `Computation.new(all_documents)`
> 3. Iterate all documents and  call `computation.calc(document)`

This strategy does not work for 100,000 documents as I will reach the memory limits of my machine immediately. The documents (JSON) are loaded into Tire objects which I then convert into Ruby Hashes.

What can I do to make this scale? I thought of the following, but I am not sure whether a) it's good to implement b) the best solution.

> 1. Initialize computation object `c = Computation.new`
> 2. Load *m* documents
> 3. `c.preprocess(documents)`
> 4. Repeat Step 2 and 3 until all documents are preprocessed
> 5. Load *m* documents
> 6. Iterate the *m* documents
> 7. `c.calc(document`)
> 8. Repeat Step 6 and 7 until all documents are processed

Also from the GC point of view I am not sure how this would work out.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you need *all* documents available for calculation at the same time? For instance, are you performing many aggregate calculations? If it is a matter of running the same *independent* calculation on all documents efficiently, then you have lots of options available. For instance, Elastic Search can be set up to do a lot of per-field or per-document processing for you. Could you give more details on the type of calculation?

Comment: @NeilSlater No, I dont' need them at the same time, that's why I have suggested the one solution I proposed. The documents can be computed independently, some however neeed some shared data I generate in the initialization process. The initialization process analyses all the documents and generates additional information used in the calculation later. I had looked into the scripting capabilities of Elasticsearch that can perform computation directly in the JVM, but that does not reflect my case. I use many different gems, fetch data from the web, compare values based on native libraries etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems to be "How do I serialize 100,000 ElasticSearch JSON objects into Ruby objects without running out of memory?". A better question would be: "How do I run calculations on 100,000 ElasticSearch documents as easily and efficiently as possible?". Since we don't know what kind of calculations you are trying to run, we'll have to keep the answer general.

1. Take [neil-slater](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2001031/neil-slater)'s suggestion and do as much in ElasticSearch as possible. For instance, ES has lots of nice [statistical calculations you can do](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/facets/statistical-facet/) in the DB/store.
2. Do preprocessing on insertion of new documents. For instance, if you know you are going to want to get counts, averages, or some other calculation against the entire set, just calculate the stats for each item before storing it in ES. If you are using Tire in Rails, add these calc methods to a before_save callback or something.
3. Avoid deserializing the ES docs into Ruby objects all together. Turning all 100,000 into Ruby objects is what is killing your memory. See if you can get performance improvements by fetching the results as straight-up JSON and use the ruby JSON gem (or some performance-tuned alternative like multi-json) to turn them into ruby hashes. It will still each some memory, but not nearly as much as full Rails model objects.
4. Try breaking the calculation into steps and feeding them as background jobs or tasks for a daemon. If they need to execute in order, you can have the first job fire off the next job as it completes.
5. If none of the above works, find a way to get closer to the data (manipulate the JSON directly with some javascript lib) or consider another data store, possibly something like PostgreSQL where you can do TONS of calculations in the DB 1000x faster than you ever could in Ruby/Rails.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for this extensive answer, although my question was stated so broad. It helped very much, I think I am on a good way now.